# How to extract the final part of the URL's path in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am using `Network.URI` to parse a url (`String`).
How can I get from the returned `URI` (`parseUri url`) the last part of the path? Or there are better alternatives than `Network.URI`?

For example from:
http://www.foo.com/foo1/foo2/bar.html?q=2&q2=x#tag

I would like to get just "bar.html"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quite easily extract just the final part from a `URI`.

Extract the `uriPath` from the parsed `URI`, and then just take in reverse until you hit a slash.

For example,

```
getFinalPart :: URI -> String
getFinalPart = reverse . takeWhile (/='/') . reverse . uriPath
```